# How to concatenate conditional RequireClaims Expressions in AddPolicy statement

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm configuring my Authorization method in this way:

```
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Branch", 
            policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
    });
```

This is perfectly working with my "Branch" Policy in the Controller.
What I need to achieve is to Allow multiple claim requirements..where the authentication happens even though only 1 of those requirements is satisfied.
I tried this way by adding the BranchManager Claim after. But it's not working.

```
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Branch", 
                policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
            options.AddPolicy("Branch",
                policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "BranchManager"));
        });
```

I also tried concatenating the RequireClaim statements.

```
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Branch", 
                policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
                                .RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "BranchManager"));
        });
```

And also it doesn't work since the System is expecting that both "Admin" and "BranchManager" claims are decleared. Is there an elegant way to achieve this: authorize if at least one of the requirements is satisfied ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dig into the source for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorisationPolicyBuilder you will see that there is a version of that method like this

public AuthorizationPolicyBuilder RequireClaim(string claimType, IEnumerable requiredValues);

The second argument needs to be an IEnumerable of the values you are after.

```
options.AddPolicy("Branch", 
                policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, new List<string> {"Admin", "BranchManager" }));
```